# Title appears right aligned!

Tags: html, css

http://www.perfectclaims.com/ppiclaimsnew/

I dont understand why the first part of the title is right aligned?

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Ian - you have some great answers here, but in the future you may wish to check out DocType (http://doctype.com/) for questions like this - hand it your website, and it'll save the code for others to examine, generate screenshots, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
```

That div is creating space. I would guess you want to give it a width of 100% to make it fill horizontally so the title below has the full width to work with.

Incidentally, I was able to find out the information easily by using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which is an extension for firefox.

Comment: +1 for both the 100% width and using Firebug (which I also used to find out).

Answer (score 3):

Because that breadcrumb div is floating in the way of it. You can move the title paragraph down manually, or you can use the CSS property `clear` to avoid this.

Comment: according to firebug, it would be enough to remove the "float: left" from #breadcrumb

Comment: In this case, yes, but I guess there's some reason to let the thing float :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're floating the breadcrumb trail to the left (and for no apparent reason, I might add). You can either remove the `float` CSS attribute from `#breadcrumb` or add `clear: both;` to `.title`.

Answer (score 0):

add clear: left; to your paragraph `<p class="title" style='clear: left;'>`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line float:left from id #breadcrumb.. Here float:left is not needed

so your code looks like below

```
#breadcrumb {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
color:#999999;
font-size:10px;
margin-top:5px;
padding-bottom:10px;
position:relative;
width:550px;
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome, place the mouse over the element, right click and select 'inspect-element'.